# Finding partial derivatives and solving $(1-x^2)^2y''=y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential

I found some difficulties with one exercise.

I have differential equation $$(1-x^2)^2y''=y$$ and I have got changes: $x=tg(t)$ and $y=\frac{u}{cos(t)}$ where $u=u(t)$.

I am not sure if I'm doing my steps right. I want to find $\frac{dy}{dt}$. And here are my steps:

1. $dx=\frac{1}{cos^2(t)}dt => \frac{dt}{dx}=cos^2(t)$
2. $dy=d(\frac{u}{cos(t)})=\frac{ducos(t)+usin(t)dt}{cos^2(t)dt}$

And now I'm confused what to do now. I don't even know if my derivative no. 2 is OK.

Comment: $x=t \  \color{red}{g}(t)$ ... $ x= \tan(t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ x= \tan(x)$ so $ \frac{dx}{dt}= \sec^2(t)$. $y=u \sec(t)$ so $ \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{du}{dt} \sec(t)+ u \sec(t) \tan(t)$. Now by the chain rule 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{dt}{dx} \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{\frac{du}{dt} \sec(t)+ u \sec(t) \tan(t)}{\sec(t)}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now differentiate again (chain rule, quotient rule, etc ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} =\frac{dt}{dx} \frac{d}{dt} \left(  \frac{\frac{du}{dt} \sec(t)+ u \sec(t) \tan(t)}{\sec(t)} \right) \\
= \frac{ \sec(t) ( \frac{ d^2 u}{dt^2}+\frac{du}{dt} \tan(t)+u \sec^2(t) ) -\sec(t) \tan(t) ( \frac{du}{dt} +u \tan(t))}{\sec^4(t)} \\
=\frac{ \sec(t) ( \frac{d^2 u}{dt^2} +u)}{ \sec^4(t)} 
\end{eqnarray*}
At this stage, one gets the feeling that your first equation should have been $(1 \color{red}{+} x^2)^2y''=y$ and you were expected to conclude that $ \color{blue}{u''=0}$.